# Осваиваю язык программирования С. Не получается сделать качественный указатель на матрицу

Tags: c++, c

В функции out не получается сделать нормальный указатель, всегда вылезает ошибка
main.c:57:21: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
 printf("%4d", mas[i][j]);

Нужна универсальная функция (способ передачи массива функции), чтобы можно было использовать ее как для первой матрицы 4 на 5, так и для второй 5 на 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5
#define M 4

int randm (int a, int b)
{
return (rand()%(b-a+1)+a);
}

void inp(int A[][M])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<M;j++)
            A[i][j]=randm(1,10);
}

void change(int A[][M], int B[][N])
{
    int i,j;
    for (j=0; j<M; j++)
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
            B[M-1-j][i]=A[i][j];
}

void out(int n, int m, int * mas)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
        {
            for (j=0;j<m;j++)
                printf("%4d", mas[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int main(void)
{
int i, j, A[N][M], B[M][N];

srand(time(NULL));
inp(A);
change(A,B);
out(M,N,(int *)B);
}
```

Comment: У вас в первых функциях всегда было `int A[][M]`, `int B[][N]` и т.п. А здесь внезапно стало `int * mas`. Почему?

Comment: @AnT в прошлых функциях не нужна была универсальность, а в функции вывода потребовалось возможность работать сразу для двух массивов, попытался делать с помощью указателей. В данном коде записан последний , не рабочий, вариант

Comment: Можно сделать просто `void out(int n, int m, int mas[n][m])` (но только в С, не в С++).

Comment: Кстати, если вопрос про С, то тег С++ - долой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос помечен одновременно С и С++. Решения, доступные в этих языках, отличаются.

- Для С у вас есть простое решение: воспользоваться VLA

  ```
  void out(int n, int m, int mas[n][m])
  {
    ...
  }

  ...
  out(N, M, A);
  out(M, N, B);
  ```
- В С++ же в вашем конкретном примере вам можно просто воспользоваться шаблонами

  ```
  template <int n, int m> void out(const int (&mas)[n][m])
  {
    ...
  }

  ...
  out(A);
  out(B);
  ```
- Универсальный способ, применимый как в С, так и в С++ (если вам недоступны VLA, вы не хотите использовать шаблоны, или вам нужен код, который будет компилироваться и в С и в С++) основан на создании промежуточного массива указателей

  ```
  void out(int n, int m, const int *const mas[])
  {
    ...
  }

  ...
  const int *const A_rows[] = { A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4] };
  out(N, M,  A_rows);

  const int *const B_rows[] = { B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3] };
  out(M, N, B_rows);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Вот универсальный способ вывода, остальные функции по аналогии

```
#include <stdio.h>

void out(int *a, size_t m, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++, putchar('\n'))
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%4d", a[j + i * n]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    int b[4][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}};
    int c[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    out(a, 3, 3);
    putchar('\n');

    out(*b, 4, 2);
    putchar('\n');

    out(c, 1, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Этот старый хак тем не менее является именно "хаком".

Answer (score 0):

Для  `int * mas`, не может быть  индексация неодномерного массива, хоть вы можете присвоить указателью начало двумерного массива.
В таких случаях:

```
void out(int n, int m, int * mas)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
                printf("%4d", mas[i * m + j]);
            printf("\n");
        } 
}
```

и вызвать

```
 out(M,N,B[0]);
```